# Y-E DATA PC Card Floppy Disk Drive (FlashBuster®/FlashBuster-U) is not working with Ubuntu kernel

Tags: ubuntu, usb, kernel, floppy

[Y-E DATA PC Card Floppy Disk Drive (FlashBuster®/FlashBuster-U)](http://www.yedata.com/support/pcm.html) is apparently not working with—the latest—Ubuntu kernel.

This floppy disk in it is Atari formatted. I just get these buffer IO errors.

```
usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=057b, idProduct=0000
usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-3: Product: FlashBuster-U
usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Y-E DATA
usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi10 : usb-storage 3-3:1.0
scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Y-E DATA USB-FDU          3.12 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Unit Not Ready
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Add. Sense: Cannot read medium - unknown format
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] READ CAPACITY failed
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Add. Sense: Cannot read medium - unknown format
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 00 46 00 00
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] No Caching mode page found
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Unit Not Ready
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Add. Sense: Cannot read medium - unknown format
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] READ CAPACITY failed
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Add. Sense: Cannot read medium - unknown format
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] No Caching mode page found
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on device fd0, logical block 0 `
```